# Is there a way to configure the pixel format using AWS MediaConvert?

Tags: aws-media-convert

I'm looking at moving some transcoding jobs from ffmpeg to AWS MediaConvert and one of the ffmpeg options that I use is `-px_fmt yuv420p`.
What is the equivalent in MediaConvert?

I couldn't find any settings relating to pixel format or chroma subsampling.

Comment: After further research, I believe that `4:2:0` chroma subsampling would be automatically used based on the codec profile. For example Baseline/Main/High profiles for H264 would all result in 4:2:0 subsampling.

Answer (score 1):

Have a look at the MediaConvert API reference guide here
https://docs.aws.amazon.com/pdfs/mediaconvert/latest/apireference/mediaconvert-api.pdf#getting-started

and have a search for 'chroma subsampling'. The available settings vary by input and output file type.

The settings for 'colorSpaceConversion' allow you to specify the color space you want for each output.

Comment: As a follow-up question, it seems that 4:4:4 chrome subsampling is not supported (unless staying within a ProRes input/output). Is that accurate?